# Many to many relationship with more than 2 tables in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I'm trying to implement a many-to-many relationship with more than two tables in Laravel.

**Migration For Relationship Table**

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('lab_form_detail', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('color_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('lab_form_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('pontics_design_id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('teeth_design_id');

        $table->integer('quantity');
        $table->string('teeth_number');

        $table->foreign('lab_form_id')->references('id')->on('lab_forms');
        $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('colors');
        $table->foreign('pontics_design_id')->references('id')->on('pontics_designs');
        $table->foreign('teeth_design_id')->references('id')->on('teeth_designs');
    });
}
```

***Lab Form Model***

```php
class LabForm extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function colors()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Color::class, 'lab_form_detail', 'lab_form_id', 'color_id')
                    ->withPivot([
                        'pontics_design_id',
                        'teeth_design_id',
                        'quantity',
                        'teeth_number'
                    ]);
    }

    public function ponticsDesigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(PonticsDesign::class, 'lab_form_detail', 'lab_form_id', 'pontics_design_id')
                    ->withPivot([
                        'color_id',
                        'teeth_design_id',
                        'quantity',
                        'teeth_number'
                    ]);
    }

    public function teethDesigns()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(TeethDesign::class, 'lab_form_detail', 'lab_form_id', 'teeth_design_id')
                    ->withPivot([
                        'color_id',
                        'pontics_design_id',
                        'quantity',
                        'teeth_number'
                    ]);
    }
}
```

I also use ***belongsToMany*** for other related models.

When I try to insert a new row, I need to use functions for the relationship to insert.
For example:

```php
$lf = LabForm::find(1);
$lf->colors()->attach(1, [
    'pontics_design_id' => 2,
    'teeth_design_id' => 1,
    'quantity' => 10,
    'teeth_number' => '30 to 40'
]);
```

As you can see, when inserting a new row, I need to use one of ***colors, teethDesigns, ponticsDesigns***. Also, I need to insert values differently which depend on the functions that define the relationship.

My question is, can I combine related values into one function and insert them all at the same time? Like:

```php
public function labFormDetail()
{
    // insert all values at once
    'lab_form_id', 'pontics_design_id', 'color_id', 'teeth_design_id','quantity', 'teeth_number'
}
```

Or should I create a model for this relationship table?
Or you may suggest your approach for this kind of relationship.

Comment: I'd use a model for the relationship table.

Comment: @IGP I would give it a try. Thanks for editing my code.